# Conditional join or query of two layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, spatial-query

I have two layers that I'm trying to conditionally join. One layer `JUNCTIONS` has junction IDs (`NAME`) and flooding volumes (`Flood_cf`) for each junction. I'm interested in identifying and symbolizing only the junctions with a flooding volume that exceeds a threshold (400 cubic feet).

The second layer `CONDUITS` contains pipe features with starting and ending nodes for each pipe. I would like to use the `JUNCTIONS` layer to identify the pipes that are surcharging (i.e. flooding). These are the pipes with starting nodes (`INLETNODE`) that match the `NAMES` from the `JUNCTIONS` layer which exceed the set threshold. Then, I would like to add a field to the `CONDUITS` layer in order to tag these pipes for symbology.

I tried doing a subquery (i.e. `SELECT FROM (SELECT FROM)` ) but I couldn't get the syntax to work. Alternatively, I could create a new feature class for the nodes that exceed the threshold, join the new layer to the `CONDUITS` layer, and export the results to a new layer. However, this process is tedious and generates a lot of extra and unnecessary files and fields. Is there a faster and a cleaner way to do this? I'll eventually have to create a model for this process because I need to run it on hundreds of files.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add your `FLOODING` field to your `CONDUITS` table.
2. Perform a Table Join on your `CONDUITS` layer:

Right-click on the `CONDUITS` layer in the table of contents -> Joins and Relates -> Join....

In box 1 use your key field `INLETNODE`. In box 2 use your layer `JUNCTIONS`. In box 3 use the field name `NAME`. Click OK.

[image]

[image]

1. Open the attribute table of your `CONDUITS` layer. Right-click on the
   added `FLOODING` field and click `Field Calculator...`. Find the
   joined `Flood_cf` field for your field calculate.